# Node file parsing by empty line not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing

I have some data in a txt file in this format:

```js
byr:1985
eyr:2021 iyr:2011 hgt:175cm pid:163069444 hcl:#18171d

eyr:2023
hcl:#cfa07d ecl:blu hgt:169cm pid:494407412 byr:1936

ecl:zzz
eyr:2036 hgt:109 hcl:#623a2f iyr:1997 byr:2029
cid:169 pid:170290956

hcl:#18171d ecl:oth
pid:266824158 hgt:168cm byr:1992 eyr:2021
```

I already have a function that parses the txt file line by line:

```js
function parse_file_by_line(folder, file_name) {
  // Read the input file line by line, creating an array of inputs.
  const input_file = path.join(__dirname, folder, file_name);
  return (input_array = fs.readFileSync(input_file).toString().split("\r\n"));
}
```

However, i want to parse on the blank lines. ( the empty spaces in the text file ). Someone suggested to split on "\n\n" Which i have tried but it ends up putting all the data into one big array element." I want to split it on the empty lines and the data between into one array element. For example, the first index would be "byr:1985 eyr:2021 iyr:2011 hgt:175cm pid:163069444 hcl:#18171d".

Comment: Use split("\r\n\r\n"). Windows has \r\n on each line ending and linux uses just \n.

Comment: @John You my friend are a life saver , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide a way to check file string. You could use `JSON.stringify` to check what kind of string your file have. By this way, you will find out what is your line ending.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const data = fs.readFileSync("./file.txt")
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.toString()));
```

In my mac, this is output.

```
"byr:1985\neyr:2021 iyr:2011 hgt:175cm pid:163069444 hcl:#18171d\n\neyr:2023\nhcl:#cfa07d ecl:blu hgt:169cm pid:494407412 byr:1936\n\necl:zzz\neyr:2036 hgt:109 hcl:#623a2f iyr:1997 byr:2029\ncid:169 pid:170290956\n\nhcl:#18171d ecl:oth\npid:266824158 hgt:168cm byr:1992 eyr:2021"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split("\r\n\r\n"). Windows has \r\n on each line ending and linux uses just \n.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `stream` approach which mean not reading all the file into memory. This is useful when working with large files. Following handles CRLF too:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
  // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```

For more info see [this](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).

Now, you can customize the for-loop to detect empty line like this:

```
 var lines = []

 for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    
    if (line === ''){
       if (lines.length > 0)
         process_chunk(lines);
       lines = [] //empty the array and make it ready for next iteration
}
    else
      lines.push(line)
  }

function process_chunk(lines) {
 //now, you have an array of consequtive non empty lines here
}
```